# C# OpenQA.Selenium Как вытащить с помощью CssSelector?

Tags: c#

Использую С# OpenQA.Selenium

Как вытащить текст в `span` исключая текст в `strong` ?

```
<span class="abc><strong>Статичный текст:</strong>Динамический текст</span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант можно использовать сторонний HTML-парсер, (`AngleSharp`, `Html Agility Pack`, ...)

```
var doc = new HtmlParser().Parse(driver.PageSource);
var childs = doc.QuerySelector("span").ChildNodes;

var result = childs.FirstOrDefault(x => x is IText)?.TextContent;

Assert.That(result, Is.EqualTo("Динамический текст"));
```

Comment: Спасибо ! Попробую разобраться.